Trying to trigger an AWS SNS topic from an Airflow DAG failure to invoke a Lambda function that creates a JIRA ticket for failed DAG
I have created a test dag which fails upon running for testing but I can't get the SNS topic to trigger after the dag fails.
Is something missing or something added stopping it from working and triggering the SNS topic? This is the Python code I've typed up that should trigger the SNS topic on DAG failure:
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from pathlib import Path
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.sns import SnsPublishOperator
import boto3
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.sns import SnsHook

DAG_NAME = 'dag_name'

# Funciton which triggers SNS notification on failure
def failure_callback(context):
    sns_notification = SnsPublishOperator(
        sns_hook = SnsHook(sns_topic_arn='My Topic ARN'),
        dag_id = context["dag"].dag_id,
        task_id = context["task_instance"].task_id,
        exception = str(context.get("exception")),
        log_url = context["task_instance"].log_url
    )

# Trigger SNS notification
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='eu-west-2')
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn='My Topic ARN',
        Message=f"DAG {context['dag'].dag_id} failed on task {context['task_instance'].task_id}"
    )

# Function to intentionally fail DAG (ONLY FOR TESTING)
def fail_dag():
    raise Exception("Intentional DAG failure for test")

# Define DAG
default_args = {
    "on_failure_callback": failure_callback,
    'owner': 'Me',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 12, 9),
    'is_prod': False
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='dag_name',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    
    # To fail task intentionally
    fail_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='fail_task',
        python_callable=fail_dag,
    )

    # Dummy start and end tasks for DAG
    start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end')

    # Dependencies (chained)
    start_task >> fail_task >> end_task

globals()[DAG_NAME] = dag

Is there anything I may be missing outside of the Python code?

Apache Airflow provides callbacks to enable additional event based functionality. Here are the official docs.
Here is an example to send an email when a specific task or operator fails:
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

def failure_alert(context):
    subject = f"Task Failed: {context['task_instance_key_str']}"
    body = "This task has failed. Please check the logs for more information."
    send_email('alert@example.com', subject, body)

... your dag code

    task = DummyOperator(
        task_id='failable_task',
        on_failure_callback=failure_alert
    )

You can also use the call back in your dag definition:
with DAG('example_dag', start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), on_failure_callback=failure_func) as dag:

Or use an SNS Topic using the official operator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.sns import SnsPublishOperator

def notify_failure(context):
    dag_id = context['dag'].dag_id
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    
    sns_publish = SnsPublishOperator(
        task_id='notify_failure',
        target_arn='arn:aws:sns:your-region:your-account-id:your-topic-name',  # Replace with your SNS topic ARN
        message=f"DAG {dag_id} has failed. Task {task_instance.task_id} failed.",
        subject=f"DAG Failure Notification: {dag_id}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',  # Ensure you have an AWS connection configured
    )
    return sns_publish.execute(context=context)
)


Would this allow me to trigger the sns topic? if so, how? That's my main issue right now.
Sorry if it's a silly question I'm fairly new to these tasks and the deadline is looming

@JPA According to the official documentation there is a SnsPublishOperator, so you can use it in conjunction with the on_failure_callback. I have updated my answer to include an example. Please upvote should this help you on your path to resolve your tasks.
